# Need help using jquery .find() to dynamically change span text in a dialog window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to dynamically set the values of the span tags in a dialog window. The way I am doing this is by going through an object array and matching the key of the object array to the class names in the dialog window (see html below). Once matched I do a .find(selector) and change the value of that span. The problem is that the

```
var myObsModal = $("#observationModal").html().trim();
$myObservationModal = $(myObsModal);
$myObservationModal.find(key).text(value);
```

is not working.  If I just set the text based on an id it works fine:

```
 $("#observationModalName").text(thisObservationDataObject['heading']);
```

Below is the complete javascript. Note I have checked that the class in the html matches the keys in the data object.

```
//allObservationArray is an array of observationDataObject 
    var observationDataObject = {
        heading: '',
        headingid: '',
        timestamp: '',
        userid: '',
        status: '',
        fileSize: '',
        priorityLevel: '',
        comment: '',
        tags: [],
        photoFiles: [],
        videoFiles: [],
        audioFiles: [],
        photoCount: '',
        videoCount: '',
        audioCount: ''
    };

var $myObservationModal
/**
 * Setup the modal with the selected observation information
 * @param {type} observationSelected
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function setupObsModal(observationSelected) {       
    var myObsModal = $("#observationModal").html().trim();
    $myObservationModal = $(myObsModal);
//Note that thisObservationDataObject has the structure of the observationDataObject shown above
        var thisObservationDataObject = allObservationArray[observationSelected];
        for (var key in thisObservationDataObject) {
            if (thisObservationDataObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log(key + " => " + thisObservationDataObject[key]);               
                if (key === "comment") {
                    $myObservationModal.find('.observationModal').val(thisObservationDataObject[key]);
                }else if (key === "heading") {
                    addDataToObsModal('#observationModalName', thisObservationDataObject[key]);
                    $myObservationModal.find('#observationModalName').attr("id", thisObservationDataObject[key]);
                }else {
                addDataToObsModal('.' + key, thisObservationDataObject[key]);
            }
        }
    }

    //Testing. This works

    $("#modalTimeStamp").text(thisObservationDataObject.timestamp);
//either approach works
        $("#observationModalName").text(thisObservationDataObject['heading']);
        //end testing

    $("#observationModal").modal('show');
}

function addDataToObsModal(key, value) {
    $myObservationModal.find(key).text(value); //<================Not working
}
```

Just for completeness here is a small portion of the html modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="observationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="observationModalName">Observation Name</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="fullView" class="container-fluid"> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- Left column -->
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover ">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Time & Date:</td>
                                            <td><span class="timestamp" id="modalTimeStamp"> </span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>File Size (KB):</td>
                                            <td><span class="fileSize" id="modalFileSize"> </span></td>                                          
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> User:</td>
                                            <td><span class="userid" id="modalUserID"> </span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Priority Level:</td>
                                            <td><span class="priorityLevel" id="modalPriorityLevel"> </span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Status:</td>
                                            <td><span class="status"> </span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Mission</td>
                                            <td><span class="mission"> </span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Sch/Bonus:</td>
                                            <td><span class="schBonus"> </span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Datatype:</td>
                                            <td><span class="datatype"> </span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
        .....
```

UPDATE
Using log statements I have discovered that the text is being set

```
console.log("here is the key and value: " + key + " => " + value);
    console.log("$myObservationModal.find(key).attr(class) " + $myObservationModal.find(key).attr('class'));
    $myObservationModal.find(key).text(value);
    console.log(" $myObservationModal.find(key).text() " +  $myObservationModal.find(key).text());
```

So the problem appears to occur after leaving the function.  I wonder if

```
$("#observationModal").modal('show');
```

is not being updated when $myObservationModal is changed

Comment: how/where are you defining and populating  `allObservationArray` ?

Comment: allObservationArray.push(observationDataObject); I updated the code to show observationDataObject

Comment: I have walk through the data object and the information is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two code snippets at the beginning of your question do completely different things.

This one selects the actual DOM element with the id `observationModalName` and changes its content in your page:

```
$("#observationModalName").text( thisObservationDataObject['heading'] );
```

This one gets the HTML code (a text string) for the `observationModal` element, then creates a temporary DOM object (`$myObservationModal`) which is not part of your actual page content, and modifies that temporary object. There is no connection between the temporary DOM object and your page content, so this has no effect on the page itself:

```
var myObsModal = $("#observationModal").html().trim();
$myObservationModal = $(myObsModal);
$myObservationModal.find(key).text(value);
```

Perhaps what you want to do here is something like this:

```
$("#observationModal").find(key).text(value);
```

That will modify the actual page content.

Comment: Awesome that worked.  I started to realize that I was creating a temporary DOM object and was trying to append it back to the HTML, however your approach of just using $("#observationModal").find(key).text(value); is much simpler and easier